# Множественные API запросы c сервера

Tags: php, api

Заранее прошу прощение, если вопрос поставлен неправильно: программирование - не моя основная специализация.

Есть API внешнего сервиса, к которому мне нужно сделать 700 запросов, чтобы получить 700 единиц информации (одним запросом не получить, разные сущности).

Я сделал вывод идентификаторов для запроса на HTML страницу и сделал AJAX скрипт, который ПО ОЧЕРЕДИ раз в секунду отправляет эти запросы. Раз в секунду потому что, если делать запросы чаще, то много ответов с ошибкой.

Вопрос: как сделать тоже самое полностью на стороне сервера?
То есть как избавиться от необходимости открывать страницу и запускать JS скрипт вручную? А например, сделать PHP скрипт, который сам будет запускаться по крону без участия человека?

Нет достаточного опыта с PHP, чтобы правильно задать вопрос в гугл. Как это называется? Асинхронные запросы? Есть ли какой то мануал, а лучше пример решения похожей задачи?

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Вам нужен cUrl, как создать запрос можно почитать по ссылке https://intop24.ru/article_20.php официальная документация здесь http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php

Comment: Если чаще чем раз в секунду не требуется, то асинхронность ни к чему. Слать несколько запросов параллельно нет смысла.

Comment: @Arendach, спасибо, изучу.

Comment: @Mike, подскажите пожалуйста тогда аналог setTimeout для PHP или как организовать отправку запросов? Просто в PHP я пока не знаю как отправить их по очереди...

Comment: а с помощью `nodejs` не получится запустить?

Comment: @Quty обычный цикл, например while, внутри которого по одному отправляете запросы, после отправки запроса можно немного поспать на sleep() / usleep()

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, к сожалению, ничего не знаю про NodeJS ((

Comment: @Mike, вот. Про существование sleep() не знал. Спасибо, изучу. Вот только вопрос - это придётся изменять время выполнения скриптов на сервере? 700 секунд выходит за стандартное время обработки PHP скрипта на среднестатистическом хостинге?

Comment: @Quty, но смотрю вы и в php не очень) с node как минимум один и тот же синтаксис.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, так и есть)) не очень. Но в PHP смогу разобраться и сделать по аналогии. А nodeJS даже нет представления, как его настроить и запустить на сервере? Или он как PHP сразу вшит в хостинг и можно начать использовать его сразу из коробки? Решаемая задача - небольшой хелпер для личных целей. Нет смысла углубляться в новый язык программирования, если можно решить быстрее. Но спасибо за предложение.

Comment: @Quty php скрипты могут быть 2х видов - отвечающие на запросы web-сервера и обычно им и запускаемые, там естественное ограничение на время соединения с клиентом, плюс доп ограничения хостинга. А так же фоновые скрипты, которые запускаются из консоли (при наличии доступа к ней), из скриптов запуска сервера или из cron. И вот какие из способов запуска возможны на вашем хостинге и каковы ограничения на время (если есть) лучше уточнять у хостера

Comment: @Mike, большое спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, буду пробовать через крон.

Comment: С кроном обратите внимание на то, что бы два скрипта не начали выполнятся паралельно в случае если один еще не завершился, а крон уже запустил следующий. Можно запускать их из cron редко и/или при старте скрипта убеждаться что другая копия не запущена

Comment: @Mike, мне нужно раз в сутки. Вряд ли столкнусь с наложением друг на друга. Но на всякий случай, да, погуглю на тему. Спасибо!